# IOError: encoder jpeg not available on OS X 10.10

Tags: python-2.7, jpeg, python-imaging-library, osx-yosemite, encoder

I have trying to install Python Image Library, and have got message that told me install success

```html
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    version       1.1.7
    platform      darwin 2.6.9 (unknown, Sep  9 2014, 15:05:12)
                  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)]
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    --- TKINTER support available
    --- JPEG support available
    --- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
    --- FREETYPE2 support available
    *** LITTLECMS support not available
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But when I run the code, got some error message which likely told me that I have not install the JPEG library

```html
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/tian/PycharmProjects/helloworld/image_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tian/PycharmProjects/helloworld/image_test.py", line 35, in <module>
    image.save('code.jpg', 'jpeg')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1439, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 471, in _save
    ImageFile._save(im, fp, [("jpeg", (0,0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 495, in _save
    e = Image._getencoder(im.mode, e, a, im.encoderconfig)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 401, in _getencoder
    raise IOError("encoder %s not available" % encoder_name)
IOError: encoder jpeg not available
```

When I searched the reason of this error in Google, most of the solution is to reinstall the PIL, but I have got the "JPEG support available" message when I install PIL, so it should not be caused by the JPEG library. Then, how should I solved this problem?

My OS is OS X Yosemite 10.10

Answer (score 1):

I solved this question by using Pillow instead of PIL, and use "form PIL import Image" instead of "import Image".